# Http 500 error after disabiling Magento 2.2.3 dotmailer module from admin backend

Tags: magento2, error, extensions, http-error-500, apache2

Magento 2.2.3, Php 7, Ubuntu 16.04 x64

I'm getting following notice on website after disabling a magento module

"This page isn’t working

exampledomain.com is currently unable to handle this request.

HTTP ERROR 500"

error.log.1 file shows following

Thu Apr 26 06:25:01.766562 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 23903] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using exampledomain.com. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
error.log file shows following

[Thu Apr 26 06:25:02.042512 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 23903] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Apr 26 06:25:02.042546 2018] [core:notice] [pid 23903] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'

so someone told me to enable `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`so I did and I got this

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Zend_Cache_Exception: cache_dir "/var/www/html/var/cache/" is not writable in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php:209 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php(180): Zend_Cache::throwException('cache_dir "/var...') #1 /var/www/html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php(87): Zend_Cache_Backend_File->setCacheDir('/var/www/html/v...') #2 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php(153): Cm_Cache_Backend_File->__construct(Array) #3 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php(94): Zend_Cache::_makeBackend('Cm_Cache_Backen...', Array, true, true) #4 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Cache/Frontend/Factory.php(158): Zend_Cache::factory('Magento\\Framewo...', 'Cm_Cache_Backen...', Array, Array, true, true, true) #5 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Cache/Frontend/Pool.php(67): Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Factory->create(Array) #6 /var/www/h in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php on line 209
```

then I gave write permission to var/cache dir and I got

> There has been an error processing your request Exception printing is
>   disabled by default for security reasons.
>
> Error log record number: 1247333171049

I checked the log record, it shows

```
{"0":"Warning: file_put_contents(\/var\/www\/html\/var\/cache\/\/mage-tags\/mage---792_TRANSLATE): failed to open stream: Permission denied in \/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/colinmollenhour\/cache-backend-file\/File.php on line 663","1":"#0 [internal function]: Magento\\Framework\\App\\ErrorHandler->handler(2, 'file_put_conten...', '\/var\/www\/html\/v...', 663, Array)\n#1 \/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/colinmollenhour\/cache-backend-file\/File.php(663): file_put_contents('\/var\/www\/html\/v...', '792_TRANSLATE_E...', 10)\n#2 \/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/colinmollenhour\/cache-backend-file\/File.php(179): Cm_Cache_Backend_File->_updateIdsTags(Array, Array, 'merge')\n#3 \/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/magento\/zendframework1\/library\/Zend\/Cache\/Core.php(390): Cm_Cache_Backend_File->save('{\"123\":\"123\",\"T...', '792_TRANSLATE_E...', Array, false)\n#4 \/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Cache\/Core.php(74): Zend_Cache_Core->save('{\"123\":\"123\",\"T...', '792_TRANSLATE_E...', Array, false, 8)\n#5 \/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Cache\/Frontend\/Adapter\/Zend.php(47): Magento\\Framework\\Cache\\Core->save('{\"123\":\"123\",\"T...', 'TRANSLATE_EN_US...', Array, false)\n#6 \/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Cache\/Frontend\/Decorator\/Bare.php(75): Magento\\Framework\\Cache\\Frontend\\Adapter\\Zend->save('{\"123\":\"123\",\"T...', 'translate_en_US...', Array, false)\n#7 \/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Cache\/Frontend\/Decorator\/TagScope.php(51): Magento\\Framework\\Cache\\Frontend\\Decorator\\Bare->save('{\"123\":\"123\",\"T...', 'translate_en_US...', Array, false)\n#8 \/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Cache\/Frontend\/Decorator\/Bare.php(75): Magento\\Framework\\Cache\\Frontend\\Decorator\\TagScope->save('{\"123\":\"123\",\"T...', 'translate_en_US...', Array, false)\n#9 \/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Cache\/Frontend\/Decorator\/Bare.php(75): Magento\\Framework\\Cache\\Frontend\\Decorator\\Bare->save('{\"123\":\"123\",\"T...', 'translate_en_US...', Array, false)\n#10 \/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Cache\/Type\/AccessProxy.php(85): Magento\\Framework\\Cache\\Frontend\\Decorator\\Bare->save('{\"123\":\"123\",\"T...', 'translate_en_US...', Array, false)\n#11 \/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Cache\/Frontend\/Decorator\/Bare.php(75): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Cache\\Type\\AccessProxy->save('{\"123\":\"123\",\"T...', 'translate_en_US...', Array, false)\n#12 \/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Cache\/Frontend\/Decorator\/TagScope.php(51): Magento\\Framework\\Cache\\Frontend\\Decorator\\Bare->save('{\"123\":\"123\",\"T...', 'translate_en_US...', Array, false)\n#13 \/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Translate.php(501): Magento\\Framework\\Cache\\Frontend\\Decorator\\TagScope->save('{\"123\":\"123\",\"T...', 'translate_en_US...', Array, false)\n#14 \/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Translate.php(211): Magento\\Framework\\Translate->_saveCache()\n#15 \/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Area.php(244): Magento\\Framework\\Translate->loadData('frontend', false)\n#16 \/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Area.php(215): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Area->_initTranslate()\n#17 \/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Area.php(142): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Area->_loadPart('translate')\n#18 \/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/View\/DesignLoader.php(55): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Area->load('translate')\n#19 \/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Action\/Plugin\/Design.php(48): Magento\\Framework\\View\\DesignLoader->load()\n#20 \/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(121): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Action\\Plugin\\Design->beforeDispatch(Object(Magento\\Cms\\Controller\\Index\\Index\\Interceptor), Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#21 \/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\\Cms\\Controller\\Index\\Index\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#22 \/var\/www\/html\/generated\/code\/Magento\/Cms\/Controller\/Index\/Index\/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\\Cms\\Controller\\Index\\Index\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)\n#23 \/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/FrontController.php(55): Magento\\Cms\\Controller\\Index\\Index\\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#24 \/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#25 \/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)\n#26 \/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/magento\/module-store\/App\/FrontController\/Plugin\/RequestPreprocessor.php(94): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#27 \/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\\Store\\App\\FrontController\\Plugin\\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#28 \/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/magento\/module-page-cache\/Model\/App\/FrontController\/BuiltinPlugin.php(73): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#29 \/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\\PageCache\\Model\\App\\FrontController\\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#30 \/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#31 \/var\/www\/html\/generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/FrontController\/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, NULL)\n#32 \/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Http.php(135): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#33 \/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http->launch()\n#34 \/var\/www\/html\/index.php(39): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor))\n#35 {main}","url":"\/","script_name":"\/index.php"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try disabling module from command line ?

```
magento module:disable Module_Name
```

and try to run upgrade and compile command one more time.

Comment: thanks for your reply, @Pravin unfortunately I don't remember module name it was dotmailer but I don't exactly remember what it was named and I think module just got disabled right but website didn't return to it normal as you must know that when a module is being disabled website to moved to maintenance mode or we can say its disabled, in my understanding it had trouble returning to normal due to some error.

Comment: Have you tried changing the permission of var folder ? try 
chmod -R 777 pub var